# Databinding error with a shared interface

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, mef

Hey I wonder if someone could help me. I try to bind my imported test modules to my view, see below for code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AvanadeTT.Controls.Views.Module"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InterfaceLibrary;assembly=InterfaceLibrary"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="600" Width="600">
     <Grid>
      <TreeView Name="ModuleTV">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:ITestTest}"        ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:ITestTest}" ItemsSource="{Binding Author}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
        <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="488,534,0,0"     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Height="31"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now my viewmodel does get the data so that is not what the problem is. The editor gives the following stacktrace and error:

```
'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.' Line number '13' and line position '14'.
```

The fusionlog shows this content:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = -------
LOG: DisplayName = InterfaceLibrary, PublicKeyToken=f004634844582dd6
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: InterfaceLibrary, PublicKeyToken=f004634844582dd6 | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\STEPHE~1.MAC\AppData\Local\Temp\dev4FB3.tmp
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TemplateProviders/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/InterfaceLibrary/InterfaceLibrary.EXE.
```

Good to know maybe is that my Interface definition is a shared assembly, this because I import via the MEF framework.

My InterfaceLibrary is being copied to my debug folder and this also shows there.

Comment: Try to strong name the assembly and add it to the GAC.

Comment: The assembly is strongly named, it's added to the GAC dynamicly. So that isn't the problem. Thanks for your responding

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your problem is line 13.  I would be surprised if your ItemsSource binding was the problem.  I would guess that there's some sort of problem finding the ITestTest type. I couldn't tell you why.